# Compare the same multiple columns of two table in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables  table 1 and table 2 ,have  common columns(a,b,c and d). What requirement is I need to match all these 4 columns(all the 4 columns should match) . If these match then Job will run and if not job will not run.

Comment: Is this compare columns name or data in table between two table?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

First of all, you should have specified database you use; PL/SQL means "Oracle".

---

Sample tables:

```
SQL> select * From table1;

         A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10        100       1000
         2         20        200       2000

SQL> select * From table2;

         A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10        100          1     --> column D is different
         2         20        200       2000
```

The following query uses *set* operators and checks whether there are any rows that exist in `table1` and don't exist in `table2` and vice versa. If so, it means that the aren't equal and query won't return any rows (so you wouldn't run that "job").

```
SQL> select dummy
  2  from dual
  3  where not exists ((select a, b, c, d from table1
  4                     minus
  5                     select a, b, c, d from table2
  6                    )
  7                    union all
  8                    (select a, b, c, d from table2
  9                     minus
 10                     select a, b, c, d from table1
 11                    )
 12                   );

no rows selected
```

OK; let's now make tables *equal* and try again:

```
SQL> update table2 set d = 1000 where a = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From table1;

         A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10        100       1000
         2         20        200       2000

SQL> select * From table2;

         A          B          C          D
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10        100       1000      --> column D is now equal to table1's D column
         2         20        200       2000
```

Query result:

```
SQL> select dummy
  2  from dual
  3  where not exists ((select a, b, c, d from table1
  4                     minus
  5                     select a, b, c, d from table2
  6                    )
  7                    union all
  8                    (select a, b, c, d from table2
  9                     minus
 10                     select a, b, c, d from table1
 11                    )
 12                   );

D
-
X          --> right; something is returned so - run the job!

SQL>
```

---

As this is a PL/SQL *problem*, just put such a query into a procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_run is
  2    l_dummy dual.dummy%type;
  3  begin
  4    select dummy
  5    into l_dummy
  6    from dual
  7    where not exists ((select a, b, c, d from table1
  8                       minus
  9                       select a, b, c, d from table2
 10                      )
 11                      union all
 12                      (select a, b, c, d from table2
 13                       minus
 14                       select a, b, c, d from table1
 15                      )
 16                     );
 17    dbms_output.put_line('Run the job!');
 18  exception
 19    when no_data_found then
 20      dbms_output.put_line('Do nothing; tables aren''t equal');
 21  end;
 22  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> rollback;

Rollback complete.    

SQL> exec p_run;

Do nothing; tables aren't equal

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> -- let's make columns D equal as well
SQL> update table2 set d = 1000 where a = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> exec p_run;
Run the job!

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```